# Ignore everything after slash if it's a number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to ignore everything after a slash if it's a number -

http://www.example.com/123abc/456/ABC/789/

Desired output is

http://www.example.com/123abc/

I have tried the following so far -

```
(https?:\/\/.*)(?=/\d+).*
```

which gives me -

http://www.example.com/123abc/456/ABC/

Many Thanks!

Comment: lol test.com really exists :D

Comment: I recommend the official example domains example.com and example.org :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
(https?:\/\/.*?)(?=/\d+\/).*
//            ^        ^^
```

Making the [repetition non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy), and enforcing the whole directory to be a number (otherwise `/123abc…` would already match it). Maybe you also want to move the first slash from the lookahead into the matching group, so that your result has the trailing slash.

Comment: Awesome-o. Works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` is greedy and will try to match as much as possible.  The `789` existence allows for a match of everything up to it.  Instead you can use.

```
(https?:\/\/.*?)(?=/\d+).*
```

The `?` makes the `.*` relucant, so it will match as *little* as possible to satisfy the expression.

However, this doesn't fulfill the requirement you described which is actually "Ignore everything after the *second* slash if it is a number."  You can use (in your specific case):

```
(https?:\/\/.*?\/.*?\/)(?=\d+).*
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this works too. Not necessary that it has to be after a second slash.